# Is there an equivalent of pagespeed for Nginx?

Tags: nginx, pagespeed

I know the pagespeed module for Apache can make the page visit faster, so, I wonder whether there is an equivalent for Nginx?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the reason why Apache has pagespeed modules, etc. Is because Apache is slower to Nginx. However I do not believe there is such a thing.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed

it is a work-in-progress
source, http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4638712

> igrigorik | http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4638885
>   Mostly just hooking up all the API's - aka, "making it work", 
>   and making it work in the context of nginx. As a reference point, the Apache
>   implementation took a while to get right even just because
>   understanding all of the gotchas of Apache's worker model and
>   surrounding API's took time - half a dozen false starts, etc. Now it's
>   solid. If someone has good understanding of nginx internals, then any
>   input, guidance, etc, would be awesome, as it would short circuit a
>   lot of that extra work. We have a design doc in progress, I'll work on
>   making it public and will share it in the project readme. In the
>   meantime, if you have any suggestions, open an issue on the repo and
>   let us know!

**Edit**: https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed is now out of beta.

Answer (score 0):

There's the start of a port over to nginx here - 
https://github.com/mtourne/ngx_instaweb

Even if the port isn't ready for prime time you can always perform the optimisations by hand.

- Turn on compression
- Reduce HTTP requests

  - merge + minify CSS
  - merge + minify JS
- Serve static content with long expiry times
- Optimise images
- etc

One of the things that pagespeed etc can't do yet is workout what JS is needed during pageload and what can be loaded later.